# TRUNCATE in transaction: dead lock

Tags: postgresql, deadlock

In a unittest we run this:

```
BEGIN;
TRUNCATE table1;
TRUNCATE table2;
...
UPDATE ...;
ROLLBACK;
```

Unfortunately this results in a dead lock if a cron job starts and this job operates on table1 and table2.

```
DatabaseError: deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 15815 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 291262 of database 290999; blocked by process 16391.
Process 16391 waits for RowShareLock on relation 291431 of database 290999; blocked by process 15815.
```

Is there a way to isolate the unittest from the cron job (to avoid the dead lock)?

We run PostgreSQL 9.0.10 on x86_64 linux

Comment: @Colin'tHart You're quite right, acquiring the locks as described in my deleted answer isn't sufficient. You need to maintain lock acquisition ordering as well.

Comment: I would have hoped the `truncate table1, table2, ..., tableN` syntax would have the semantics "acquire all locks and only then truncate all tables". Wouldn't having that solve the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TRUNCATE` should be used only when it is certain that no other session is using the table at the same time. Otherwise `DELETE` should be used. It's slower (if the number of rows is significant), but it's designed to support concurrent access within the rules of the current isolation mode.

The [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-truncate.html) says:

> TRUNCATE acquires an ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock on each table it operates
>   on, which blocks all other concurrent operations on the table. When
>   RESTART IDENTITY is specified, any sequences that are to be restarted
>   are likewise locked exclusively. **If concurrent access to a table is
>   required, then the DELETE command should be used instead.**

If `DELETE`'s slowness is not acceptable, to avoid the deadlock with 100% certainty, you'd need to put the entire sequence into a critical section, both in the unit test and in the cron job. A critical section is entered by requesting an explicit lock before any other operation, such as in:

```
BEGIN
 SELECT pg_advisory_xact_lock(1); -- (1 is arbitrary: choose any value reserved for this purpose by your apps)
 TRUNCATE ...;
 TRUNCATE ...;
 ...processing...
ROLLBACK;
```